# Windows 7 Ribbon UI Win32 API Code

Tags: winapi, ribbon

I'm a big fan of "Pure Win32 API Code". I use Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 and I'm surprised with it's Ribbon UI. Can we do that in Pure Win32 API? I don't mind complex coding... I use Code::Blocks with MinGW, installed with TDM-GCC 4.6.1_1. Please help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ribbon is available as a native control in Windows 7 and Windows Vista with Platform Upgrade installed. The API is COM-based (like many other recent API additions).

See [Windows Ribbon Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN for complete documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nikita Nemkin. I've visited the above link. After reading few pages I've started downloading Windows 7 SDK. I'll try those example. But I actually wanted to do all that in "Pure Win32 API" because when I write programs in "Pure Win32 API", they are standalone and don't require any DLLs until I create them. I neither have money to buy Visual Studio nor I want to use Cracks to register it. I just want to go with "Pure Win32 API". And one more thing, I don't know MFC and .Net language.

Comment: @RavikaJain - you don't need Visual Studio to use COM. It should be possible to use it using any Windows-based compiler - MinGW included. Also note that the Win7SDK includes a compiler/linker; you only really need to buy Visual Studio if you want the editor/debugger functionality or other tool support.

Comment: But designing Ribbon UI needs XML file that contains Ribbon's Markup Code. And MinGW doesn't compile XML file. I'm a bit confused!

Comment: Can you put the XML file alongside the exe or embed it in a resource?

Comment: Please read the docs linked above carefully. [Compilation workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316924(v=vs.85).aspx) is explained and even illustrated.

Comment: Regarding development environment, [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) is free. Together with Windows 7 SDK it should cover all your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I got that working. I removed MinGW and installed Windows 7 SDK. Code::Blocks integrates well with it. Now I'm enjoying new APIs in Windows 7. Thanks everyone for your answers.